# Extracting source and target of a DirectedEdge

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I extract source and target of a `DirectedEdge[{1,2},{3,4}]` ? Should I use something like

```
a \[DirectedEdge] b = DirectedEdge[{1,2},{3,4}]
```

But this one is not working

Comment: `First` and `Last`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only assign multiple variables simultaneously through a `List` head, for example `f[a,b] = f[3,4]` won't assign a and b to 3 and 4, but `{a,b} = {3,4}` will.

Therefore change the head from `DirectedEdge` to `List` using `Apply` (`@@`):

```
{a, b} = List @@ DirectedEdge[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
```